# Tensor coordinate transformations: cosine matrix vs rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, tensors

I have a tensor $\varepsilon(\vec r)$ and want to get $\varepsilon(\vec r')$. After some googling I've got confused, should cosine matrix to be used or coordinate transformation matrix?
Some sources [like this](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_1_Vectors_Tensors/Vectors_Tensors_13_Coordinate_Transformation_Tensors.pdf) suggest to use $\varepsilon(\vec r')=Q\varepsilon(\vec r)Q^T$, where Q is a matrix of projections of the new basic vectors on the old ones.
While other sources, like the tensor [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) tell to use the coordinate transformation matrix $\varepsilon(\vec r')=R\varepsilon(\vec r)R^{-1}$.
Please, stop my suffering. Which way should I use to transform dielectric tensor in a simple Euclidean space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll find that both are equivalent, since the coordinate transformation/cosine matrices are orthogonal ($Q^T = Q^{-1}$).

Comment: What if my transformation is x'=0.1x, y'=0.1y, z'=0.1z? In this case, I get a Q=0.1*I (I -- indentity). And $Q^T$ is not $Q^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, in that case your transformation is to a non-orthonormal coordinate system, and you should use a coordinate transformation matrix of the second type you mention. Be wary that you have to take into account some extra things when transforming into a non-orthonormal coordinate system, like the metric tensor, etc.